# How to scan and remove random characters in the end of paragraphs in UTF text

Tags: javascript, regex, utf

Here is the doc I want to filter(https://gist.github.com/jianbo/2192f8f1d25a422ed6a5)

each paragraph end with random strings like this `Q: U  A" j$ w& p`
and I want to remove them, the idea I have is to scan for any match with characters start with a full stop and end with more than 3 spaces.

This is what I have, but how do I detect the front full stop and three white spaces?

Example Data (but please look at the [GIT text](https://gist.github.com/jianbo/2192f8f1d25a422ed6a5) ):

> 这么长this should stay  时间的面试，不  知道会怎么样: Q: U  A" j$ w& p                   这么长时间again this should stady的面试，不知道会怎么样

My code

```
 data.match(/[a-zA-Z~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|\;':",./<>? ]/g).join('')
```

This output

```
"this should stay  : Q: U  A" j$ w& p                   again this should stady"
```

Comment: Do you mean `:` colon or `.` full stop and is the random string the same length always?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add specials characters to the regex:

```
var data = 'yourstring';
data.replace(/[^\w\sñáóí\&\$\"]/gi, '');
```

Comment: Hi Jean, this gives me "this should stay   Q U  A" j$ w& p                   again this should stay", but I only want to match '  Q U  A" j$ w& p'. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Is there any common patterns we can use to match?

Answer (score 0):

Those seemingly errant characters come after a U+3002 Unicode Character "IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP."  You didn't say what UTF, but it looked like something from the web so I'm going to guess most likely you would download as UTF-8.

I don't know what regex engine you're using and if you have support for Unicode, so I'm providing a pretty generic "perl" command-line solution.  This regex does not require the 16- or 32-bit libraries; it will work in regular byte-mode on a UTF-8 file:

```
perl -pe 's/(?=\xE3\x80\x82)(.*\xE3\x80\x82).*/\1/' your_file
```

The first part just checks to see if we have a U+3002 Ideographic Full Stop, which in UTF-8 is a three-byte code point with the hexadecimal value E3 80 82.  If the assertion is true (i.e., we have a U+3002), it captures up to and including the full stop U+3002 character.  If you don't want to include the full stop character, just move the closing parenthesis from after the \x82 to after the first asterisk, i.e.:

```
s/(?=\xE3\x80\x82)(.*)\xE3\x80\x82.*/\1/
```

Again, not provided any details about the regex engine/flavor or programming language, etc., this may need to have the match piece plucked out, escaped, and replacement string plucked out for a separate call, etc., but I think I've given you enough direction that I hope you are able to find value in my response.